# Nuxt: How to log errors on production

Tags: nuxt.js, error-logging

I got an error on my nuxt production environment.

```
Server error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.
```

Where can I find detailed error logs?

I start the server with this command:

```
npm run start -- --port 3333
```

In my console I get only this output:

```
ERROR  Request failed with status code 403                                                        16:40:07

  at createError (node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)
  at settle (node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:17:12)
  at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:236:11)
  at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:323:22)
  at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:505:15)
  at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1204:12)
  at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
```

But this does not help. I would like to see what has been sended to the server and what came back as a response. (I guess there is somewhere an authentication problem)

**EDIT:**
It seems that this it the only output from nuxt. There is no additional log. But you can add to your project a tool like sentry to get more informations. Unfortunately the error log in sentry is also not enough in my case. Is there another way to get more insides?

Comment: Use Axios intercepter or Axios error handler from there show toast message or pass the message to vuex and according to that display page.